# Multicol elements behaving differently between Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

A weird multicolumn problem is keeping me from getting a layout to look the way I want it. I'm trying to get elements in a container to align in columns.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="element">lorem</div>
  <div class="element">ipsum</div>
</div>
```

Here is a JSfiddle that shows what I mean:
https://jsfiddle.net/2sobjo12/3/

If you open this fiddle in Chrome or Opera, you will see the two elements stacked on top of each other. In Firefox or IE/Edge however, they are horizontally aligned (which is the way I intended it).

Does anyone know what is causing this behavior? And, more importantly, what can I do to fix it?

--- EDIT ---

To clarify, let me explain what I'm trying to do. The container in question is a mega menu, the elements are submenus in said container. Thus, I want the browser to distribute the submenus evenly in the container, even though they can vary significantly in height. Compare this fiddle in Chrome and Firefox to see what I mean:

https://jsfiddle.net/2sobjo12/15/

Firefox does a nice job, while Chrome insists on placing the second element under the first one for some reason, and leaves the fourth column completely empty.

Answer (score 1):

In your css, add float:left. 
float property specifies whether or not an element should float.It  can be used to wrap text around images.

```
li {
  background: white;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
  float:left;
}
```

Complete css as requested

```
.container {
background: green;
width:100%;
float:left;
padding: 15px 15px 10px;
}

.container .element {
  background: white;
  display: inline-block; 
  margin: 0 10px 5px 0;
  float: left;
  width:25%

}
```

Comment: If I do that, there is a one column wide space between the two element, caused by the margin-bottom of the Element. It becomes visible when I change margin-bottom to padding-bottom: https://jsfiddle.net/2sobjo12/7/

Comment: Did you add  margin-bottom: 0 0 5px 0; to li style as per my answer @snorri

Comment: Oh wow - no, I totally hadn't caught that. And it works like a charm! But now I've got to know: Since when does margin-bottom take four values? I have never seen that before, is this official or a clever CSS hack?

Comment: After experimenting a bit more with this approach, I still see a pretty big problem: Now the elements aren't displayed as boxes anymore when they contain longer text. Instead, this text is spread across several columns: https://jsfiddle.net/2sobjo12/9/ Specifically, "float: left" seems to counteract the effect of "display: inline-block".

Comment: @snorri Check the changes

Comment: That works, but isn't really what I was looking for any more. I need the multicolumn arrangement so that the browser will distribute elements with various heights evenly across the width of the container. Without multicol, there will be unsightly gaps between elements. In the example of this fiddle between elements 1 and 7: https://jsfiddle.net/2sobjo12/11/

Comment: @snorri, So what is your question now? As I see you wrote

And, more importantly, what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Sorry, I had submitted my comment before being done by accident and have just edited it.

Comment: There will always be gaps because of the width/text in each column. @snorri